# what is the 'x :=' part mean in a hoare triple?

Tags: notation, hoare-logic

In [Hoare logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic), there's a thing called a [*Hoare triple*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic#Hoare_triple), e.g.$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\{x = 2\} & & x := x+1 & & \{x = 3\}
\end{array}.
$$
What does '$x :=$' mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, it's an assignment, but it's not part of Hoare logic.

It means whatever it means in the programming language you're using.

A Hoare triple in general looks like $\{P\}\; C\; \{Q\}$ (stolen from the [all-knowing wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic)), where:

- $P$ and $Q$ are assertions about the state of the system before and after $C$ is executed; and
- $C$ is some piece of code.

So the meaning of $x :=$ depends entirely on the semantics of the code.

Assuming someone hasn't written this as a trick, $:=$ is usually used as an assignment operator (to avoid confusion with $=$ as equality), so in this case the line should be read as $x := x + 1$, i.e., the line of code is incrementing the variable $x$.

If the triple were written in a C-like language, you could write it as $\{x=2\}\; x=x+1;\; \{x=3\}$, or similarly in your favourite language.

Comment: To be more specific, `:=` is assignment in Algol-derived languages such as Pascal.